# ¿Como saber cuantas veces se repite un dato con LinQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

necesito saber como obtener cuantas veces se repite un dato cuando la fecha sea distinta de null, se escribir la siguiente query para obtener lo que busco:

```
SELECT count(*) total_repetidos, IdCasillero FROM lockers.pedidos
where Fech_Out <> 'null'
GROUP BY IdCasillero
having total_repetidos > 1
order by total_repetidos desc
```

pero necesito hacerla desde LinQ, lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```
var conIdCasillero = (from ped in context.Pedidos
                      where ped.FechOut != null
                     group ped by ped.IdCasillero into repetidos
                     where repetidos.Count() > 1
                      select new Pedidos
                      {
                        IdCasillero = repetidos.Key
                      }).ToList();
```

pero esto solo me trae los datos que se repiten.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el método extensor Count(), te quedaría algo así:

```
var count = context.Pedidos.Count(ped => ped.FechOut != null);
```

Esto te devolvería un entero.

Comment: Esto devuelve el conteo de los pedidos que no tienen la fecha null. No es lo que OP quiere

Comment: Debería de mejorar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Esto devuelve una lista de elementos con las propiedades `Casillero` y `Cantidad`:

```cs
context.Pedidos
    .GroupBy(x => x.IdCasillero)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && g.Fech_Out == null)
    .Select(y => new { Casillero= y.IdCasillero, Cantidad = y.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Nandico. Entiendo que  tu respuesta devuelve los elementos con Casillero y Cantidad, pero el usuario preguntó por un count. No está mal, pero tal vez faltó un poco.